# Postfix won't receive e-mails for virtual domains

Tags: postfix

It's been 3 days I've been searching for a solution, but it seems there is no use. Postfix can send e-mails just fine from the server, but it can't receive them. Everytime I try writing an e-mail to one of the virtual domains, I get "Relay access denied"

Here is the postfix config:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
relay_domains = $mydestination
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

maillog:

```
Oct 14 08:42:44 ns519796 postfix/smtpd[19172]: connect from mail-yk0-f177.google.com[209.85.160.177]
Oct 14 08:42:44 ns519796 postfix/smtpd[19172]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-yk0-f177.google.com[209.85.160.177]: 554 5.7.1 <user@example.com>: Relay access denied; from=<myemail@gmail.com> to=<user@example.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-yk0-f177.google.com>
Oct 14 08:42:44 ns519796 postfix/smtpd[19172]: disconnect from mail-yk0-f177.google.com[209.85.160.177]
```

Comment: Please include the relevant logs and your virtual_alias_maps.

Comment: I've included maillog, are there any others I need?
Also, virtual_alias_maps contains only one line, it is "user@domain.com user"

Comment: Where have you defined your virtual domains, then? Because I would expect them to be in virtual_alias_maps.

Comment: For now, I'm just testing one domain. I'll be sure to define the others later. I'm using Webmin+Virtualmin control panel, if this is of any help.

Comment: I'm sorry everyone, the problem went away when I added a new entry to virtual_alias_maps, which was "domain.com domain.com" I don't know why is this needed, but it is what solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Does mydestination include your example.com?

```
mydestination = example.com, $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
```

Relay access denied is not a per-mailbox error, it says the domain you are looking for isn't accepted here and assumes you want to relay to that domain (as it isn't a local domain)

Issues with alias maps would be related to something like Mailbox not found errors, not relay errors.

Email Address Errors:

```
rcpt to:reject@jacobdevans.com
554 5.7.1 <reject@jacobdevans.com>: Recipient address rejected: Access denied
```

Domain Errors:

```
rcpt to:proamdtechie@gmail.com
454 4.7.1 <proamdtechie@gmail.com>: Relay access denied
```

Comment: Actually, the virtual_alias_maps was enough to recognize the domain. The problem went away when I added a new entry to virtual_alias_maps, which was "domain.com domain.com" I don't know why is this needed, but it is what solved my problem. But thanks for your answer anyway.